# Javascript - Capitalizing first letter of each word in a string

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a bot for discord and using this project to teach myself javascript. I have a predefined string set to message variable and I want this to script to change the first letter of each word in the string to a capital, but so far the function is only returning the message as it was spelt. I cannot understand why

```
var string = message.substr(message.indexOf(" ")+1);

function capital_letter(str)
        {   
            str=str.split(" ");

            for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i<x, i++;) 
            {
                str[i] =     str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
            };

        return str.join(" ");};
```

If message = "ring of life" I would expect the output to be "Ring Of Life"

Comment: Review your `for` loop, you make a mistake using a `,` where a `;` should be. The loop should be defined like: `for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i < x; i++)` or even better `for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some syntax errors, here's a corrected version of your captial_letter function:

```
function capital_letter (str) {
  str = str.split(' ')
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const firstChar = str[i].charAt(0)
    str[i] = firstChar.toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1)
  };

  return str.join(' ')
};
```

The biggest one was to separate your loop parameters using `;` instead of `,`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
```

p.s. looks like you might benefit from a better IDE :-)

Comment: While this answer is showing the correct solution, it is wrong in saying that OP’s code produces a syntax error.

Comment: how is `i<x, i++;` not a syntax error?

Comment: It’s a comma operator which is followed by the required `;` and by an empty statement. Try this, it should output only `1`: `for (var i = 0; i < 10, i++;) console.log('loop'); console.log(i);`.

Comment: ah, so it parses but it isn't what's intended?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w{3,}/g, function (l) {
   return l.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + l.slice(1);
});
```